# How To Emit Only Gallery IMGs from Batflat CMS

Tags: image, content-management-system, template-engine

If you make a Gallery in [Batflat CMS](https://batflat.org), the template tag it creates will generate its only Bootstrap HTML for a gallery. What if I just want to emit IMG tags for the gallery items, instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Gallerymod custom module. That way, your customization may likely survive a Batflat Update.

1. Copy inc/modules/galleries as inc/modules/gallerymod.
2. Remove the lang folder and Admin.php in your gallerymod folder.
3. Change the Name and Description inside the gallerymod/Info.php, as well as the comments. I used static strings instead of code. Also in this file, inside the install function and uninstall function, remove code inside those so that it does nothing on install or uninstall.
4. In your gallerymod/Site.php, look for the `$assign[$gallery['slug']]` assignment, and on the following line, add:

```
$assign[$gallery['slug'] . '-alt1'] = $this->draw('gallery-alt1.html', ['gallery' => $tempAssign]);
```

Also, where you have the namespace line set as `namespace Inc\Modules\Galleries;`, change it to `namespace Inc\Modules\Gallerymod;`.

5. In your gallerymod/view folder, create a gallery-alt1.html file and add these contents:

```
{loop: $gallery.items}
<img class="photo-{if: $value.title}{$value.title}{/if}" alt="" class="img-responsive" src="{?=url($value.src.lg)?}">
{/loop}
```

6. Now activate this inactive module in Batflat's admin system. You'll notice that it has no admin panel -- because it doesn't need one. You already have the Galleries one. Do not deactivate the Galleries module because the Gallerymod module relies on the Galleries module.
7. Now, from your custom theme template, you can call this by varying how you called the old slug. So, if your old way of calling the gallery was something like `{$gallery.home-photos}`, then you would merely tack on the "-alt1" on the end and call it like `{$gallery.home-photos-alt1}`. I like to wrap these in a DIV wrapper with an ID on it so that I can address it with CSS, jQuery, or Javascript.
8. In the Batflat Admin system, go back and edit your image titles in the gallery. Treat those titles like a slug (lowercase alphanumeric phrase with dashes) because these are used as class names on the IMG tags in gallery-alt1.html, and you may want to address these individually in CSS, jQuery, or Javascript, later on.
9. Refresh your browser and you may see the source code display something similar to:

```
<div id="hidden-images" class="hidden">
  <img class="photo-man2" alt="" class="img-responsive" src="https://example.com/uploads/galleries/2/15831273220.jpg">
  <img class="photo-woman1" alt="" class="img-responsive" src="https://example.com/uploads/galleries/2/15831272980.jpg">
  <img class="photo-man1" alt="" class="img-responsive" src="https://example.com/uploads/galleries/2/15831272540.jpg">
</div><!-- hidden-images -->
```

Just remember that if you update your version of Batflat, that you may need to reapply this customization again -- it depends on what was done in the update to the existing Galleries module.

If you have different tastes as to how you want to format your images, just edit your gallery-alt1.html file. Plus, you can make multiples of these for different situations, such as gallery-alt2.html, gallery-alt3.html, etc. You can even make it emit JSON instead of html so that you can insert it into a Javascript block in your theme.

Another tip for debugging, in case your site won't load or the admin system breaks, is to edit inc/core/defines.php and change the DEV_MODE to false. That way, PHP will show you every error and that might help you in debugging what might be wrong.